# Blunt edges of an octahedron by Region

Tags: regions, mesh

Why does the octahedron constructed by the following code have blunt edges ?

`Region[ImplicitRegion[Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] <= 1, {x, y, z}]]`

[image]

How to improve it?

If it is rotated, situation gets worse.

`Rotate[Region[  ImplicitRegion[Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] <= 1, {x, y, z}]], 
 30 Degree, {0, 0, 1}]`

[image]

There are options like MaxRecursion or PlotPoints for 
`Plot3D`
but I can't find find similar options for
`Region`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeRegion.html) with the option [`MaxCellMeasure`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxCellMeasure.html):

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
    ImplicitRegion[Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] <= 1, {x, y, z}], 
    MaxCellMeasure ->. 01]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @imidak, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` with the method `"Semialgebraic"`:

```
BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
 ImplicitRegion[Abs[x] + Abs[y] + Abs[z] <= 1, {x, y, z}], 
 Method -> "Semialgebraic"]
```

[image]